# Vegetable mill versus using a food processor for vegetables

Tags: tomatoes, italian-cuisine, mixing, milling

What is the advantage of using a mechanical vegetable mill (the utensil which in Italian is called "passaverdura" or "passaverdure") as opposed to using an electric food processor for vegetables?

The only thing I could think of is that a mechanical vegetable mill makes it easy to separate the tomato peels when passing the tomato through it.

[image: passaverdure]

[image: passaverdure]

Here is an example of a food processor for comparison:

[image: food processor]

I've also found the following Wikipedia link to the utensil I describe:

[Food Mill](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food_mill)

Thank you for your insight.

Note: A vegetable food processor can also be called a vegetable mixer as this link demonstrates:

[Vegetable Mixer](https://www.formfonts.com/3D-Model/4313/1/e2020-movable-furnishings/e1010-commercial-equipment/e20-furnishings/e10-equipment/equipment-furnishings/vegetable-mixer-c01/)

Comment: What do you mean by a "vegetable mixer"? It is not a word that is common in English, and if you only say "mixer" then it refers to the machine with two rotating wire "baloons" for beating egg whites and pancake batter, and it will not do anything sensible with most vegetables. So I think something got lost in translation here. Can you please post an example of the machine you mean?

Comment: Thanks, I've included comments in my post for a picture of an electric food processor, but don't have enough reputation to include the extra picture. Could you please edit my post to uncomment and include the picture? Thanks.

Comment: There is no working link to the original picture of the food processor in your post, could you please give it here in a comment? I'll edit it in.

Comment: Just remove the spaces after https.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advantage of a *passaverdura* (or *passe-vite* in French, also known as Foley Mill in the US) is that like you said it will, depending on the coarseness of the screen, keep back undesired matter, such as pips, skins and strings. Personally, I use it mostly for apple sauce and also mashed potatoes (they achieve a higher level of fluff and fineness than with a masher).

Assuming that by a vegetable mixer you mean a stick mixer for puréeing (among other things), using that implement will not remove the aforementioned unwanted matter, which can make the consistency deviate from what you want it to be.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've updated my post. I also found the name mouli or mouli grater for what you call pass-vite or Foley mill. I've actually find two types of mouli gaters, not sure what the difference between them is.